# postgres - window function - date difference within a groups

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, date-difference

I searched and saw potential results but with my skills I'm not able to adapt them.

I have a table:

| date | record status |
| --- | --- |
| 1.10.2022 | open |
| 2.10.2022 | waiting |
| 3.10.2022 | approved |
| 5.10.2022 | open |
| 6.10.2022 | waiting |
| 8.10.2022 | approved |
| 10.10.2022 | open |
| 12.10.2022 | waiting |

and need the date difference between 'open' and 'approved' within groups starting with 'open' and ending with 'approved'. The last group is not yet approved. There the date difference is between the last open and today (=15.10.2022 just as example)

| date | record status | group/rank | date diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.10.2022 | open | 1 | 2 |
| 2.10.2022 | waiting | 1 | 2 |
| 3.10.2022 | approved | 1 | 2 |
| 5.10.2022 | open | 2 | 3 |
| 6.10.2022 | waiting | 2 | 3 |
| 8.10.2022 | approved | 2 | 3 |
| 10.10.2022 | open | 3 | 5 |
| 12.10.2022 | waiting | 3 | 5 |

Questions then:

1. How do I define the groups. I thought maybe with a rank because the orig table has thousands of rows
2. How does the date diff function look like that considers only open and approved plus the special case where the record is not yet approved
3. How to apply this date diff to the groups only

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I constructed a littler bit more complicated case. https://dbfiddle.uk/d0VxIotY

Answer (score 0):

Your idea was good; a CTE to manage the case where you need to use the current day was all you were missing (See `EXISTS`).

```
WITH RankedStatus AS (
    SELECT MyTable.*,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RecordStatus ORDER BY Date) AS Rank
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT RS.*,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT FROM RankedStatus WHERE Rank = RS.Rank and RecordStatus = 'approved')
       THEN MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Rank)
       ELSE CURRENT_DATE END
       - MIN(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Rank) AS DateDiff
FROM RankedStatus RS
```